# Import from the tests module

Tags: python

I have in `tests/__init__.py` this construct:

```py
try:
   import mock
except ImportError:
   from unittest import mock
```

and in other files I have

```py
from tests.mock import Mock
```

However, it doesn't work. Python 3.8 complains "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.mock'`". Any idea, how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to specify the module `tests`, your file has to be named `__init__.py` (so use two underscores before *and after* the name, like with `__init__` etc.).

The path `tests.mock` would only be valid, if `tests` was the name of a package (but it isn't, it's just a module). To get this right, you should either `import tests` and then use `tests.mock.Mock` (you could also assign `Mock = tests.mock.Mock` for convenience) or use `from tests import mock` and use that.

Here is some follow up documentation, but it focusses more on the internals of importing:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: That missing double-underscore was mistake here, not in reality. However, otherwise you are correct. The only thing which works is `from tests import mock` and then I can just use `mock.Mock`. And yes, your method with variable would work as well. Thank you.